# Subversion in combination with composer dependencies

Tags: svn, dependencies, composer-php

I want to manage my project with subversion and the project requires dependencies managed by composer.

What is the best practice doing that?

I can add my composer.json with the required dependencies to my trunk.
Then I run a composer update in my working copy.
As far as I know i should exclude the folders created by composer from my trunk because they don't need to be copied into the repos. Is this correct?

If i do another checkout i have to do a composer update again. Is this correct?

And if i do an export i have to do another composer update.

The main question is: Is it possible to handle the composer dependencies like svn:externals? If i do a checkout or a export subversion should download the dependencies by itself. Is that possible? Additional i want to be able to do a composer update later by hand.

Sorry but i am a little bit confused about the integration of composer into a subversion repository. Maybe anyone is able to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You commit both the `composer.json` and the `composer.lock` of your project into your repository and exclude the `vendor` folder from being committed - after you ran `composer update` once.

After that, you only ever run `composer install` to install exactly the dependencies you got when last running update:

- Checkout fresh from SVN -> `composer install`
- Grab an update from SVN -> `composer install`

The only situation where you run `composer update` is when you WANT to update your dependencies.

And one note regarding svn:externals: While in theory these are capable of doing the same as Composer, i.e. "hardcoding" (in a way) the exact revision of some other repository you are using in your current repository, this is rarely ever used. Usually you point your svn:externals to the trunk branch. But this is a risk: If you go back to an earlier revision, you won't get that earlier version of your dependency! You could include the revision being used externally into the svn:externals link, but I found this to be rather cumbersome to manage the last time I used SVN (way before Composer was started). I wouldn't recommend using these if you can use Composer instead. Also note that most Composer packages are hosted on Git based repository platforms like Github or Bitbucket, so there would be no way to include them as svn:externals anyway.

Comment: why do i need to commit composer.lock to my project when excluding vendor folder. I thought the .lock file is a lightweight information about the current content of my vendor folder, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, and that's what you want to preserve to be able to recreate it later. Otherwise anyone checking out your project at a later date will get randomly different versions of your dependencies! Besides the fact that running `update` is a command that takes considerable amount of time compared to only `install`. Without the lock file, running `install` is in fact `update` because without the recorded versions, Composer must consider all existing versions to calculate the best match.

Comment: i use subversion instead of git because as far as i know git-code is always public. I can install subversion on my private server if i dont like to share it with others. Please correct me if i am wrong but i cannot use git without sharing my code.

Comment: You are wrong. Git has nothing to do with Github, and even there you can open a paid account and have private repositories. Bitbucket allows private repositories even with free accounts. And you don't have to use a server at all, Git will work locally and/or with patches exchanged via mail if you want.

Comment: Hmm, ok. But i like to host my private code on my own server, not local and not on foreign servers. If it is possible to install git on a private root server and handle it like subversion then i should think about it. Although i am very happy with svn, it did very good work for me in the past. But I will search the web for the options i have with git and maybe i'll try it. For now i am going on to use svn. Thank you very much for your help an i hope you get lots of upvotes if others have the same questions.